# How to save a Java object in Jython/Python

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, jython

I'm building a Python UI using Tkinter. For the needs of the program, I've to connect Python with Java to do some stuff, so I'm using a simple Jython script as a linker. I cant use Tkinter with Jython because it's not supported.

`Python (ui.py) -> Jython (linker.py) -> Java (compiled in jars)`

To call the Jython function in Python I use `subprocess` as follows:

**ui.py:**

```
cmd = 'jython linker.py"'
my_env = os.environ
my_env["JYTHONPATH"] = tons_of_jars
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, env=my_env)
```

Then, in the Jython file, `linker.py`, I import the Java classes already added on the JYTHONPATH, and I create an object with the name `m` and call to some functions of the Java class.

**linker.py:**

```
import handler.handler
m = handler.handler(foo, moo, bar)
m.schedule(moo)
m.getFullCalendar()
m.printgantt()
```

The thing is that I've created a `m` object, that will be destroyed after the execution of `jython linker.py` ends.
So the question is: Is possible to save that `m` object somewhere so I can call it from `ui.py` whenever I want? If it's not possible, is there any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `pickle`? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickle_%28Python%29

Comment: I've just tried the `pickle` module with a simple Python script and works. But it doesnt work for my work as I've to save a Java object. It gives methe following error: `raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__` . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved it by using `ObjectOutputStream`.

```
from java import io

def saveObject(x, fname="object.bin"):
    outs = io.ObjectOutputStream(io.FileOutputStream(fname))
    outs.writeObject(x)
    outs.close()

def loadObject(fname="object.bin"):
    ins = io.ObjectInputStream(io.FileInputStream(fname))
    x=ins.readObject()
    ins.close()
    return x
```

Comment: Been a while, but do you remember how you avoided or handled ClassNotFoundExceptions when loading the object from file?